# DateTime parse undefined method `year'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string to DateTime and i'm experiencing an error when I try tp drop the year:

```
undefined method `year' for "Monday, Aug 25, 10:30":String
```

Controller

```
dates = []
temps = []
dt = []

@data['data'].flatten.each do |data|
  dates << data.keys
  temps << data.values
end

dates.flatten.each do |date|
  dt << DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%A, %b %d, %H:%M")
end
```

json

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-08-25 10:30:00": 12.6}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't clear because you're not showing your use of the year method. But, note that you've left out `%y` from your strftime string. I would recommend playing around in rails console to get the methods you're looking for. For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> DateTime.parse("2014-08-25 10:30:00")
Mon, 25 Aug 2014 10:30:00 +0000
[2] pry(main)> DateTime.parse("2014-08-25 10:30:00").year
2014
[3] pry(main)> DateTime.parse("2014-08-25 10:30:00").strftime("%A, %b %d %y, %H:%M")
"Monday, Aug 25 14, 10:30"
[4] pry(main)> DateTime.parse("2014-08-25 10:30:00").strftime("%A, %b %d %y, %H:%M").year
NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for "Monday, Aug 25 14, 10:30":String
from (pry):4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thanks dankohn, I should of mentioned i;m trying to drop the year out all together.